# Se pueden agregar/editar columnas en Inbox de GXFlow?

Tags: genexus

¿Es posible agregar o quitar columnas en tiempo de diseño del componente Inbox de GXFlow en una aplicación Genexus?

La pregunta aplica tanto si estoy usando el cliente default de GXFlow como si usara el componente WFEntryPoint para embeber el Inbox en mi aplicación web.

Estoy en GX Evolution 3 U6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta corta es no, tanto el cliente estándar como el wfentrypoint (que es solo un wrapper de este) se distribuyen compilados, no admiten "tiempo de diseño". El que si lo admite es el Custom Client, del cual distribuimos un xpz para poder modificarlo.

De todas formas, salvo que quieras agregarle alguna columna propia, no me imagino la utilidad de poder hacerlo en diseño cuando se puede hacer en tiempo de ejecución. Talvez lo que necesitas es que cada usuario no tenga que reconfigurarlo y que se inicialize automáticamente con un diseño que te parezca mas adecuado. Si es caso, lo vemos, si bien no lo soportamos explícitamente te puedo pasar un truco que se aproxima a la solución.

Las columnas disponibles son acotadas y no se pueden agregar dinámicamente. Solo puedes ocultar o mostrar las que están disponibles. Si necesitas otra información que no esta disponible en las columnas te conviene agregarla en el asunto de la instancia

Comment: Sería bueno que compartas ese truco, para completar la respuesta. Incluso si el autor no lo necesita, otro quizás sí.

Comment: La columna que quiero agregar no es propia, es la columna "Owner" de la instancia del proceso. Y si, la idea es que todos la vean por defecto.

Es más, busqué la manera de agregar columnas en tiempo de ejecución y no pude. ¿Cómo se haría esto?

Comment: De hecho si necesitaría saber ese "truco". Porque lo que me interesa es que todos los usuarios vean esa columna por defecto.

Comment: Ya encontré la manera de agregar columnas en tiempo de ejecución (apretando en la flechita de alguna columna e ir a la opción "Columns" para  marcar/desmarcar las columnas correspondientes). Igual esto no resuelve mi problema. Es más, no aparece la columna "Owner" en el Inbox (me imagino porque la misma es un atributo de la Instancia de Proceso y no de la Instancia de Tarea).

Comment: Si, las columnas disponibles son acotadas y no se pueden agregar dinámicamente. Solo puedes ocultar o mostrar las que están disponibles. Si necesitas otra información que no esta disponible en las columnas te conviene agregarla en el asunto de la instancia.